# Angular 4 Form not updating on patchValue

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

In my project I am trying to upload image to Firebase and then generating the link and updating it in my form but for some reason it is not getting update, but when I do refresh then I can see my changes.

There are 3 main things which I am doing

1. Getting image from URL and generating Blob

   ```
     public getBlob(url) {
       return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
         const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.responseType = 'blob';
         xhr.onload = function(event){
           const blob = xhr.response;
           resolve(blob);
         };
         xhr.open('GET', url);
         xhr.send();
       })
     }
   ```
2. Save blob in Firebase storage and generate URL (imageSaveService file)

   ```
   storageURLForPhoto(oldURL) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
     this.getBlob(oldURL)
       .then((blob) => {
         this.firebaseStorage.ref('file.png').put(blob)
           .then(snapshot => {
             resolve(snapshot.downloadURL);
           })
       });
   })
   ```

   }
3. Get URL and update Form

   ```
    this.imageSaveService.storageURLForPhoto(link).then((imageLink) => {
     this.group.patchValue({
       questionImageUrl: imageLink,
     });
   });
   ```

But while patching this value I am not able to update the view. I want to show this change in view as soon as this value get patched.

Comment: please provide some more data like for controller data

Comment: Try to call `this.group.updateValueAndValidity()` after patch